# How to make jQuery slider sensitive to work properly on iphone?

Tags: javascript, jquery, iphone, html, slider

In one of my project I am using slider like following(similar to given below).

How can I make this more sensitive so that it work efficiently in iPhone.Currently it is not properly working in iPhone.When I drag slider its response is not good. This works well with Samsung Galaxy.

Please Help

```
<!doctype html> 
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>jQuery UI Slider - Default functionality</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script src="jquery.ui.touch-punch.js"></script> 
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css" />
  <script>
  jQuery(function() {
    jQuery( "#slider" ).slider();

  });
  </script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="slider"></div>


</body>
</html>
```

If I add 'jQuery mobile' will it help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding the `step` parameter with a small value for example:

```
$("#slider").slider({
   min: 0,
   max: 10,
   step: 0.1
});
```

Comment: Could you please tell me why do we use step?

Comment: step defines how many moving points there are on the slider, the more the smoother is the sliding.

Comment: Thanks for reply. But when I try to slide the slider in iPhone the whole page moves.Is there any proper way to select the sliders and then move in touch devices? Because First time I am using the touch screen devices.

Comment: Your answer was very helpful.Your answer plus some z-index helped me. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Download this https://raw.github.com/furf/jquery-ui-touch-punch/master/jquery.ui.touch-punch.js and include it on your path. It will solve your problem.

Comment: I have no idea how or why, but it now works at least a lot better than it did, indeed.